# Rebooting modem only fixes speed for short period

Tags: networking, internet, connection, modem, dsl

My internet speed is far below its normal speed, when I restart the modem the connection will go back to it's normal speed, but only for a matter of minutes, then it drops way down again. I'm on AT&T ADSL using a relatively old 2701HG-B Gateway.

Comment: This is the type of problem only your ISP can solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your speed goes way down after minutes, then the chances are high that your upload speed has reached its capacity.

Whenever you do a download, confirmation packages are sent back. When your upload is full, confirmation packages are not sent directly and are queued up. Due to this, downloads are stalled too, and internet appears to be very slow.

The best way to troubleshoot this, is by first making sure everything is disconnected from the internet, except for one device. Then from that device run a speedtest. Measure and ensure that the speed normally is perfect. If this is not the case, you need to call your ISP because they need to do maintainance on their network. If the speeds are correct, then someone or something on your network is uploading a lot. By setting up a Quality of Service and/or limiting the bandwidth upload to below its capability, the problem should be gone.

Comment: Tech came out today. The houses wiring was bad.